# How can I remove an object from my array using mongoose and node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

How can I remove an object from my array? I am currently using express/node and mongo/mongoose. I am struggling to remove a specific object from my array. Here is what I have so far.

```
// Favorites object
{
  _id: "12931402dnfervo34fjo3",
  favorites: [
      {id: 1, name: "test"}, // I want to delete this (at index 0)
      {id: 2, name: "test2"},
      {id: 3, name: "test3"},
  ]
}
```

```
// DELETE /user/{id}/favorites/{index}
router.delete('/favorites/:itemid', auth, (req, res) => {
  Favorites.updateOne({
    _id: req.session.user
  }, {
    $pull: {
      "favorites": {
        "id": req.params.itemid
      }
    }
  }, {
    safe: true,
    multi: true
  })
    .then(response => res.status(200).json(response))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({
      message: err.message,
      error: true
    }))
});
```

is there something I am missing from this code?

Comment: Usually `_id` in MongoDB's document would be of type `ObjectId()`, first check what `req.session.user` is getting printed as, Usually if it's a string & your `_id` is of type `ObjectId()` then convert string to `ObjectId()` prior to query ! If not if both are strings better test it on DB first !!

Comment: Try convert `req.params.itemid` to number.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample document the `id` field in the `favorites` array is integer, but you are querying with `req.params.itemid` which is usually string.

Converting that to integer should help.

```
$pull: { "favorites": { "id": parseInt(req.params.itemid) } }
```

Comment: Wow it worked. thanks so much. I feel stupid but none the less thanks a lot